# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC ( open function for excel )

Tags: vb.net, excel, project-server-2007

I have developed a web application that read from excel sheet . It's working fine when I run the website at vs local host . when i upload the the website application in server 2007 . I goth the errore message below :

Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Line 37:         xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("test2007.xlsx"))

your help is highly appreciated